# How to generate GraphQL schema changelog

Tags: graphql

GitHub publishes a GraphQL schema changelog at: https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/changelog.
It looks like they are using a tool that automatically generates this changelog by comparing the new version of their GraphQL schema with the previous version.

I am looking for a way to do the same for my company's GraphQL schema.
Is there a free and open-source tool that can help generate a GraphQL schema changelog?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check changelog by using [apollo studio](https://studio.apollographql.com/)

If you upload your schema to apollo studio by using [rover](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/rover/)

apollo studio automatically make changelog

you can use it for free except for a few analysis tools.

and i don't know exactly, but you can get notification by linking plugins.